# non-blocking communications in MPI: order of messages

Tags: c++, mpi

1. What happens if a processors sends exactly the same message to the same destination with the same tag? When the receiver wants to read it, does it read the last one?
2. What if two different processors send the same message (same tag) to one processor? which one it receive and in what order?

3- How we can know how many pending messages from a specific processor are in the queue in order to receive all of them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question seems quite theoretic and should at least be accompanied by a clear example, preferably with code. Why don't you try something like philosophy,stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Mark: I disagree. In the context of MPI, the questions are valid and have a clear answer: 1: Two messages with the same `tag` and `source` are sent to the receiving process, which can receive both by two calls to `MPI_Recv`. 2: It will receive both, in random order (depending on which of the two message passing operations will be initiated first). The `tag` argument doesn't influence which messages are sent or received and in what order, it just provides a mechanism for distinguishing messages.

Comment: @mort the questions are valid and have a clear answer, but were asked in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mort, I have one more question ... how we can find out how many messages (of the same tag) have been sent by a specific processor  but not completed? ... In my code, I know that worker A has send (asynchronously) three messages, but master processor wont see them and keeps waiting, but if worker A send messages by "Send()" (blocking), it will receive them in time!!